# Notepad++ When you save a file, can you automatically run a program on that file?

Tags: notepad++, macros

I want to run a linter on my source code when I save a file (CTRL-S). Is it possible to run an external command on a file when it is saved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I am aware, in the strictest sense, there is no direct option run a program directly after saving. That said, it's likely you can get (functionally) similar behavior when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> with the steps below...

**Save and Execute With Ctrl + S**

*Install NppExec*

Normally, a regular Notepad++ macro combined with an item from the *Run* menu would likely be the simplest route to the desired behavior. However, commands from the *Run* menu don't currently seem to be allowed as macro actions by default.

To bypass this issue, we need a plugin called `NppExec`. This plugin allows us to write moderately improved macros (command scripts) for running programs from Notepad++. Particularly, it allows us to combine saving a document and running a program (which normally isn't possible, as noted).

To install NppExec:

- Open the Plugin Manager (*Plugins* → *Plugin Manager* → *Show Plugin Manager*).
- Find `NppExec` in the plugin list and mark it.
- Click `Install`.

After installation, you will need to restart Notepad++ as indicated.

*Create A Command Script*

Once Notepad++ has been restarted, open the *Plugins* → *NppExec* → *Execute...* window ( <kbd>F6</kbd> ). In the text field, place the commands you wish to execute (in order) on separate lines:

```
NPP_SAVE
# ... Another command here ...
# ... Another command here ...
```

As a small aside, it isn't exactly clear to me what you wish to do with the file (regarding your linting process), so my apologies that the example above isn't more complete.

---

*Note that each `# ... Another command here ...` is simply a placeholder for this example. Importantly, `#` signs do not actually represent comments in NppExec... this is just my shorthand. =)*

---

*Available Commands*

Given that we know we wish to save first, we can use `NPP_SAVE` to start the command script. `NPP_SAVE` is an `NppExec`-specific command which tells Notepad++ to save the current document.

In general, for the remaining commands, you will likely either invoke those commands directly (assuming they are `NppExec` commands or items registered at the command line, whose output matters little) or use e.g.  `NPP_RUN cmd /k somecommand.exe` (or other variations on `NPP_RUN cmd`) to spawn a new `cmd` window (which can often be preferable).

Anything that can be run from the command line (including batch files and scripts) are likely viable options for your commands. Notepad++ environment variables are also available. The most common one you are likely to use is `$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)` (best referenced with double quotes i.e. `"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`), which gives the full Windows path to the saved version of your current document.

It's worth mentioning that, similar to `Run` in the normal *Run...* dialog, `OK` in the *Execute...* window will perform your commands immediately. This allows you to test their functionality prior to saving them. Likewise, the `Command(s)` field is persistent between runs.

Once you are happy with the command script, you will want to choose `Save...`, give the script an appropriate name and select `Save` again to keep it for later use. Close the *Execute...* window when finished.

*Adding The Command Script To A Menu*

We can now add our `NppExec` command script to a Notepad++ menu so it can be assigned a shortcut:

- Go to *Plugins* → *NppExec* → *Advanced Options...*.
- Select the command script in the `Associated script:` dropdown menu in the lower left.
- Click `Add/Modify` to add it to the `Menu items` field just above.
- Optionally, mark the checkbox next to `Place to the Macros submenu` to add the command script to the main *Macro* menu. Otherwise, it will appear as an option under *Plugins* → *NppExec*.
- Click `OK` to finish.

Restart Notepad++ as indicated and verify that the command script now appears as an menu entry at the bottom of either the *Macro* menu or *Plugins* → *NppExec*.

*Adding Hotkeys To The Command Script*

Finally, to reassign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>:

- Open *Settings* → *Shortcut Mapper...*.
- On the *Main menu* tab, highlight the entry for "Save". Click `Clear` at the bottom of the window to clear the hotkey settings for that item ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> ).
- Select the *Plugin commands* tab. Scroll down and highlight the entry for your `NppExec` command script (identified by name). It will likely be the last item in the block for the `NppExec.dll` entries.
- Click `Modify` and set the appropriate hotkey options (mark `Ctrl` and choose `S` from the dropdown).
- Click `OK` to save the new shortcut settings and `Close` the *Shortcut Mapper...*.

Your command script should now be trigged by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (no restart necessary).

---

*You should note that, regardless of the hotkey combination you assign, the normal version of `Save` will still be associated with the File → Save menu item and toolbar icon (the single blue diskette).*

---

Comment: Lord bless you for your comprehensive and well-formatted answer! This is beautiful 

Comment: Is this normal behavior for Notepad++?  I've noticed that files saved for the first time (using `NPP_SAVE` in the script); subsequent commands consider the file none existent.

Answer (score 2):

My Notepad++ [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) saves two extra files with each <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

It makes a [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) of the file (provided the source file is a CSS, JS, or HTML file) and, a pre-compressed Brotli file from that minified file -- all in one fell swoop.

[This helpful guide](https://studiofreya.com/2016/07/09/minify-css-with-notepad/) got me started...

1. Create a batch file

**mfy.bat**

```dos
if not exist %1 (
    echo file does not exist %1
    goto :eof
)
set run_lint=0
set ext=%~x1
set nam=%~n1
set fullpath=%~dp1
set full_min=%fullpath%%nam%.min%ext%
set full_br=%fullpath%%nam%%ext%.br

if "%ext%"==".js" (
    set run_lint=1
)
if "%ext%"==".css" (
    set run_lint=1
)
if "%ext%"==".html" (
    set run_lint=1
)
if %run_lint%==1 (
    if "%ext%"==".js" (
        npx google-closure-compiler --js="%fullpath%%nam%%ext%" --js_output_file="%full_min%"
    ) else (
        npm exec --no -- html-minifier "%fullpath%%nam%%ext%"  -o "%full_min%" -c "C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\html-minifier\html-cli-config-file.conf"
    )
    IF EXIST "%full_br%" DEL /F "%full_br%"
    "C:\Program Files\PeaZip\res\bin\brotli\brotli.exe" --quality=11 --large_window=27 "%full_min%" -o "%full_br%"
) else (
    echo This is not a file to minify: %1
)
```

2. Save that mfy.bat file in your Notepad++ user folder located at: **%APPDATA%\Notepad++**
3. Download and install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/).
4. Open CMD window and run: **npm install html-minifier -g**
   found in [github.com/kangax/html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) and configure the `html-cli-config-file.conf` to your liking.
5. Install **[npm install --save google-closure-compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-compiler)** to minimize your JS files. I had to use this one because it supported logic `<` and `>` within my JS files. It also has the benefit for checking your JS code for errors.
6. In Notepad++ add plugin NppExec (Plugins -> Plugins Admin -> NppExec)
7. Go to (Plugins -> NppExec -> Execute NppExec Script...) and add `NPP_SAVE` to the first line, followed by `$(SYS.APPDATA)\Notepad++\mfy.bat "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`. Click on **Save ...** to save the script as “Minify”.

[image: (Plugins -> NppExec -> Execute)]

8. Go to (Plugins -> NppExec -> Advanced Options) to add menu item for “Minify”. Choose Minify under Associated script, press Add/Modify button. Choose “Place to the Macros menu”.

[image: (Plugins -> NppExec -> Advanced Options)]

9. Restart Notepad++
10. Install [PeaZip](https://peazip.github.io/peazip-command-line.html) as application (or use `npm install brotli`, adjust `C:\Program Files\PeaZip\res\bin\brotli\brotli.exe` in mfy.bat file accordingly if you do not install the PeaZip application.)
11. and finally, in order to get it working when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> I followed [@Anaksunaman](https://superuser.com/a/1295528/618318) instructions.

I hope this helps someone.